# Button KeyPress Not Working for Enter Key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keypress

I have a button for which I set the `KeyPress` event.

```
this.myButton.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.myButtonEvent_keypress);

private void myButtonEvent_keypress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)
     {
          // do something
     }
}
```

Now whenever the Space key is pressed, I get the event triggered. This part works fine.

But for some reason, the Enter key press is not triggering the `KeyPress`
event. Also <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> are not working.

How can I make the button receive Enter key press?

UPDATE:

I tried below too without any luck

```
this.myButton.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(myButton_Click);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a [`Button`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button(v=vs.110).aspx) has focus and you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> the `Click` event raises.

So to handle <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> it's enough to handle `Click` event and put the logic you need there.

So you just need to use `button1.Click += button1_Click;`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
}
```

If you really want to know if <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> was pressed, you can hanlde `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode== Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter");
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Space");
    }
}
```

Comment: How to find keyboard key from EventArgs e? i.e., whether it's Enter or Space

Comment: @don You don't need to check for Enter and Space, if you put your logic in `Click` event, it automatically run when you press Enter or Space on button.

Answer (score 2):

Enter and space can be handled using click event.

```
this.myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
```

Comment: Remember, this is a button. Not a text box.

Comment: Please see UPDATE above.

Comment: Winforms or webforms?

Comment: It's a winforms thingy

Comment: How to find keyboard key from EventArgs e?

Comment: @IgorQuirino Your answer is correct but needs more details and formatting like I did in my answer. Anyway +1 for your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

The Button control in WinForms will eat <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, and a few other special key's press events. One method to intercept these events is to override Control.ProcessDialogKey. Or you can override IsDialogKey to say if a key should be handled as a special case.

A another option is to set KeyPreview = true on you parent Form. Then you can handle all KeyPress events at the Form level and use Form.ActiveControl if you need to see what control has Focus

Comment: If you want to know which key is pressed, you can simply handle `PreviewKeyDown` event without need to create a custom inherited button and override `ProcessDialogKey`. Also if you use `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` event for button, you can't receive `Enter` key. Also `Click` event handle both Enter and Space. Hope you find my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815127/3110834) helpful:)